# jQuery Accordion - div not scrolling in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-ui-accordion

I have the following accordion:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />hello
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
 $(function() {
   $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
     fillSpace:true
   });
 });

 $(window).resize(function(){
    $("#accordion").accordion("resize");    
 });
```

Everything is working fine in Firefox, but in Chrome the "Section 1" div doesn't add a scrollbar even though there is content overflow. I have to manually resize the window before the scrollbar shows up (within the div). Firefox detects the overflow and shows the scrollbar by default. Anyone have an idea as to what is happening? I wouldn't even mind forcing the scrollbar to always show, but I couldn't even get any styles to apply to the div or the accordion.

Comment: looks good to me: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZGNA/

Comment: The problem is that I would like the inner div's to display overflow scrollbars, and not the entire page. Firefox does this by default, and so does Chrome... but only after I resize the page. Very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `fillSpace: true` with `heightStyle : 'fill'` as it is [deprecated](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-autoheight-clearstyle-and-fillspace-options-merged-into-heightstyle).

**Edit**

```
 $(function() {
   $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
     heightStyle: 'fill',
     autoHeight: false
   });
 });
```

CSS:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content{ overflow:auto !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip stackErr, I went ahead and applied that change but unfortunately still no scrollbar with Chrome on initial page load.

Comment: @user2507484 add `autoHeight: false`

Comment: @user2507484 if you specify the height for the div, it should force scrollbars

Comment: great, it's now working when I first load the page and the overflowing div is active! If I close and reopen the div though, the scrollbar goes away again.

Comment: @user2507484 add a `$(window).trigger('resize')`

Comment: @TecHunter Adding $(window).trigger('resize') with a slight delay did the trick! Thanks a lot for the help guys, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

add a `$(window).trigger('resize')` to trigger all height/width calculations for the plugin